# QGIS Server automatically includes port numbers in the GetCapabilities response URLs. How can I change this?

Tags: qgis-server, getcapabilities

I have a QGIS server up and running, but my GetCapabilities response always serves all URLs with port number included. Problem is that these URLs only work without port number. How can I make sure the port number is not used in the GetCapabilities request? I am not sure if this is something I should fix in a config file from QGIS Server, or maybe in the web server configuration.

I have a lighttpd web server which is exposed on port 8080. However if I expose this on port 80 (default from lighttpd) my GetCapabilities will not show the port number. Problem is that we are not allowed to expose port 80, so this is not an option.

(Maybe) some relevant information: 
Lighttpd.conf:

```
server.document-root = "/"
server.port = 8080

server.modules += ( "mod_setenv" )
server.modules += ( "mod_fastcgi" )
server.modules += ( "mod_accesslog" )
server.modules += ( "mod_rewrite" )

server.errorlog = "/dev/stderr"
accesslog.filename = "/dev/stderr"

setenv.add-environment = ("QGIS_PROJECT_FILE" => "/geo-map/source.qgs")

fastcgi.server = (
  "/" => (
    "mapserver" => (
      "socket" => "/tmp/mapserver-fastcgi.socket",
      "check-local" => "disable",
      "bin-path" => "/usr/libexec/qgis/qgis_mapserv.fcgi",
      "min-procs" => env.MIN_PROCS,
      "max-procs" => env.MAX_PROCS,
      "max-load-per-proc" => env.MAX_LOAD_PER_PROC,
      "idle-timeout" => env.IDLE_TIMEOUT
    )
  )
)
```

[image: here you see part of the GetLegendGraphic where 8080 is generated, but the link works without its port number.]
here you see part of the GetLegendGraphic where 8080 is generated, but the link only works without the port number.

Comment: I'm confused by the statement that `However if I expose this on port 80 (default from lighttpd) my GetCapabilities will not show the port number.`  that sounds like correct behaviour any http:// url is expected to be on port 80, so the port number is omitted.  I can't see why it is an issue

Comment: So on my local machine I have a setup with lighttpd exposed on port 80. Because this is the default of Lighttpd, a http://localhost will give me the standard page of QGIS Server. But since I'm not able to expose on port 80 in our work environment, I'm only allowed to expose Lighttpd on port 8000 and higher. Because of this Lighttpd listens to http://localhost:8080 and (I think) therefore a getcapabilitites request also generates 8080 after every url. Point is that these URLs don't seem to work. I only get a getlegendgraphic etc if I remove the :8080 from the URL manually.

Comment: Somehow I want to make sure that :8080 is removed from the generated URLs by QGIS Server, so I have working services. Right now, my services cannot be displayed in QGIS Desktop

Comment: But if your web server is running on port 8080, and thus QGIS server is running on the same port, then the URLs in the GetCapabilities response will need to include port 8080.  Looking for a solution that removes the port number seems wrong.  Better to work out why the requests don't work.  Is it possible that you somehow have two web servers running?

Comment: No we really have one webserver running. We do run within a containerplatform who makes reroutes of the localhost. So maybe I have to configure on the containerplatform side. I look into it.